# Windows 10 can't mount ISO. Says file is corrupted. WIndows 7 OK

Tags: windows-10, mount, iso-image

After upgrading to Windows 10, I am unable to mount many ISO files I had.  It keeps saying "The disk image file is corrupted."  I have about 10 of these ISO files and they all come up with the same error.

I searched for many solutions with Google and none of them helped.  I've tried to make the iso default for Windows Explorer.  I have tried to uninstall all 3rd party software for virtual CD's.  I have tried using many 3rd party mounting software.  All of them gives me an error.  I even tried copying the files to another drive and a USB drive and it gives me the same errors.

I know the files are good.  So I tried the ISO files on another PC running Windows 7 and it worked instantly with no errors.  It mounted and the data was in perfect condition.

One thing weird is that I have tried mounting a Windows 7 iso I download from Microsoft and it mounted without problems.

Now these files worked when I was on Windows 7 on the original PC.  Once I upgraded to 10, they no longer work. Windows says it's corrupted.  3rd party software just says error, can't mount.  Copy files to another PC with Win7, works perfectly as it should again.  I'm confident this is a Windows 10 problem.  Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score -1):

Please download Linux ISO file. Use Unetbootin to install it into a usb stick and boot from this usb stick. Linux can mount any corrupted iso or IMG files. Or maybe the image file you are mounting isn't in the format or sequence windows wants / demands it to be, hence the error(which comes to all the linux based .img files i try to open)

any of these can be true, so just boot from linux os, and then locate the iso or imgage file you wanna mount and mount it and you r done:)

If you want to make the image file open i windows, then you can follow these steps....

1. Create a new img fie in windows, and check whether it opens properly or not. So this will be the file which you wanna shift your data from your orrupted or old img file to
2. Just boot to linux and open your old/corrupted img file and mount it
3. copy everything in there and mount the new empty img file.
4. past everything into the empty iso file and you are done. just boot to windows and check whether it mounts or not(it probably should, because if there is any corrupted files inside the iso/img file, linux shouldn't be able to copy or detect them)

I had an android .img file which had a small corrupted file, i applied these methods and it actually worked fine for me..

Its common to expect your img file to be corrupted, especially if you r opening it regularly in VM or such...Besides, all systems will have atleast one corrupted file, which of course may be the case with your corrupted file as well. Cheers b/w:)